# Is 1800 Leap year or not?

Tags: algorithm

Is 1800 leap year?

I tried to solve this problem => 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/day-of-the-programmer/problem

And it says 1800 is leap year, though my calculation says it isn't.

[image]

Also when I try to find on google.com, it says like below.

[image]

My code is below.

```
bool isLeapYear(int year) {
   if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
       return true;
   else
       return false;
}
```

Comment: In the Julian calendar, yes.  In the Gregorian calendar, no.  The entire point of the problem is that Russia switched from one calendar to the other.

Comment: I don't really see where that question is related to programming or algorithms. Since I can't see the problem statement without logging into the website, I can only suggest reading it more carefully. Maybe their definition of leap year is different. Otherwise there is an error on your site and I believe nobody here is able to tell you what you should do.

Comment: @Maras There's not an error on the site; see my answer and btilly's comment. Also, you can just click the background behind the login box to make it go away.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about calendar systems, not programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code correctly implements a test of whether a year in the **Gregorian** calendar is a leap year. However, the challenge explains that Russia didn't switch to that from the Julian calendar until 1918, and in the Julian calendar, a leap year is any year divisible by 4.

Comment: So before 1918, it is true if it is divisible by 4, and my code is for years after 1918?

Comment: @O.o Right (although take note of the special handling needed for 1918 itself).

Comment: It isn't leap year. What is needed here??

Comment: @O.o It skips some days. See the challenge for details.

Comment: Wow, I saw it now, how can it be like that?

Comment: There are many other countries or even separate towns (Shanghai) that started the Gregorian calendar on some special date. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar

Comment: @Gangnus Yes, but that's not relevant to this question, which as indicated by the HackerRank challenge, is only about Russia's switchover.

Comment: SO supposes that the question/answer will be useful not for the asker only. Later other people will come with a similar problem, and that political/geographical/astronomical information could be useful. If you try to make your answer better, more elaborated, the whole pair question/answer will become more useful and can deserve reopening.